# xamarin android: Listviewitemclick doesn't trigger when I click a multiline textview inside the listitem

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a listview, there is a simple textview and a multiline textview inside a listitem. Basically the list item click doesn't trigger because of the multiline textview, but if I set the focusable property of the multiline textview to false then the click is work if I tap the simple textview.

My problem is that the list item click doesn't trigger when I tap the multiline textview, just only work if I click somewhere else.

What could be the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

muiltTextView.Click+=muiltTextView.Parent.OnClick();//i assumed that the lsitItem is the parent.

*i don't recommend to use this way because it's not how android meant to be work

Comment: Thanks. Finally I created a similar solution. Otherwise I think the original problem is that the multiline textview is stay clickable after I set its clickable and focusable property to false. I don't understand why.